# Outside electric outlets should be 20amp or 15?

Tags: electrical

The previous owner ran a circuit for outlets in my unfinished basement but I have little use for them. It would be convenient to just tap into that circuit so I can have one electric outlet on the outside on each side of the house. Maybe even eliminate most of the outlets in the basement.

However, it's only a 15 amp circuit and, in the interest of doing it the right way, my impression is that a 20 amp circuit would be better cause "power tools". Also, the wife envisions a water feature and some outside lighting.

But then the question remains about what to use in the garage. It makes even more sense, to me, to run a 20 amp circuit for wall outlets there, including one on the outside by the garage door though I don't really use power tools or envision any kind of workshop out there. There is an office next to it and I thought I would just tap into that lighting circuit for a few ceiling lights in the garage.

[This answers my question in part](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/39205/what-size-breaker-and-wire-do-i-need-to-run-2-gfci-receptacles-and-a-flood-light) Don't know how I missed that but a few details are missing.

Comment: Are you asking about preference or code requirements? If the former, you seem to have made the case for new 20A circuits yourself. That's what I'd do. You'll probably have an interior use for the 15A circuit down the road anyway.

Comment: @isherwood Yeah, I think I'm stating the obvious but it made me feel better to type it out loud.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably use the 15 ampere basement circuit to power outdoor lighting, and water feature (just make sure it's all GFCI protected). If you're going to be using power tools outside (power washer, electric mower, trimmer, hedge clipper, etc. Then you're going to want to run a new 20 ampere GFCI protected circuit.

If there are only a few lights in the office on the circuit, you can surely power a few more garage lights with that circuit. Though you'll want to make sure that's all that is on that circuit, or you could end up overloading the circuit.  If you want to add receptacles in the garage, you'll want a dedicated 20 ampere GFCI protected circuit. If you're going to be running a bunch of power tools, you might want to consider a 20 ampere multi-wire branch circuit. In which case you can split each receptacle, and power the top/bottom from the separate legs of the circuit.

Before you make a final plan, make sure you know for sure what's on any circuit you're tapping into. Guessing here could lead to overloaded circuits, and nuisance tripping.

Comment: You're pretty much confirming what I'm thinking but it feels better to have someone say the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

A water feature and outside lighting aren't going to care about 15A vs. 20A, they are small loads.

As far as a common 2-prong power tool, they don't care about 12AWG (20A) vs 14 AWG (15A) unless the cable run is fairly long.  Punch it into a [voltage drop calculator](http://i.4cdn.org/s/1502199288354.jpg) and see for yourself.  You're perfectly allowed to use some or all 12AWG on a 15A circuit, if you want to reduce voltage drop.  If it is all 12AWG, you can use a 20A breaker, but if the sockets are 15A it must have at least two of them (the common dual receptacle will suffice).

Do not remove receptacles "you don't have a use for".  It's a lot of work, and it does nothing for you.  If you have a very underused circuit, feel free to tap it for additional outlets - there is no limit to the *number of outlets* on a circuit, and you can "tee" a circuit.  So that underused line is a good one for outdoor receptacles, lighting or water features.

At least check Code to make sure you aren't eliminating one required by Code, which you would then be obliged to put back in when you sell your house.  Second, check with a realtor to make sure doing so won't reduce your home's value.  Lots of people want power in their basement so they can plug in a vacuum cleaner without running an extension cord.  Or the next guy might want a workshop.

Comment: Is there a limit to the number of outlets on a circuit? Source please...

Comment: only if you're in Canada (the CEC sets a limit, but the NEC does not)